# What is Dynamic and Static in computer science generally means?

Tags: computer-science

I've heard many terms like "Dynamic binding", "Static binding", "Dynamic linking", "Static linking" and "Dynamic loading".

All I know is when some terms have vocabulary dynamic, it means at runtime. But why "Dynamic" and "Static"? According to dictionary, dynamic is something keep changing, "Happen at runtime" equals to "Something keep changing"? I don't see the point why people using dynamic to mean "Happen at runtime".

Comment: Yes, but _dynamic_ has such a nice ring to it in a bullet-list :)

Answer (score 0):

"Dynamic linking" - if your program is dynamically linked with a number of shared libraries, then you can modify these libraries **independently** from the main program (provided that you don't change the interface between them). So, yes - libraries might keep changing, and they do. An example: you upgrade Linux, then you typically get new versions of many system libraries.

"Dynamic binding" - if you work with programming language, which supports dynamic binding, then your function call can be bound to the function body dynamically based on an argument the function is called upon.